# React-hook-form - watch causing an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form` inside of a Form component.

The Form component has to update its container - App component.

The From component should not have a submit button.

Therefore, a `watch` method of `react-hook-form` has to be used.

The App component preserves the data using `useState` hook.
I'm trying to update the data inside the App component using prop callback.
This causes an infinite loop.

App component

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';

import { Form } from './Form';
export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ name: 'David' });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {data.name}!</h1>
      <Form setData={setData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Form component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export const Form = ({ setData }) => {
  const { register, watch } = useForm();
  const formData = watch();
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(formData);
  }, [formData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Form comp</h2>
      <form>
        <input name="name" {...register('name')} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fjegsn?file=src%2FForm.tsx) - note - to see the infinite loop issue, change the App component and change the setData prop to the setter function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **setData** to update the state in the **App** component every time the form data changes. However, this also triggers a re-render of the **App** component, leading to an infinite loop.

If you want to update the state in the **App** component when the form data changes, you might want to move the form state management to the **App** component

App component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form } from './Form';

export const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: 'David' });

  const updateFormData = (newFormData) => {
    setFormData(newFormData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {formData.name}!</h1>
      <Form formData={formData} updateFormData={updateFormData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Form Component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export const Form = ({ formData, updateFormData }) => {
  const { register, watch } = useForm();

  const watchedData = watch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the parent component's state only if the form data has changed
    if (JSON.stringify(watchedData) !== JSON.stringify(formData)) {
      updateFormData(watchedData);
    }
  }, [watchedData, formData, updateFormData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Form comp</h2>
      <form>
        <input name="name" {...register('name')} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, the form component (Form) receives the form data and a function to update it as props. It triggers the updateFormData function only if the form data has changed, preventing an infinite loop. Check [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3sdzqw?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2FForm.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

whenever FormData is changed and  it triggers a re-render, which, in turn, causes the useEffect in the Form component to be executed again, leading to an infinite loop.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export const Form = ({ setData }) => {
  const { register, watch } = useForm();
  const formData = watch();
  const [dataChanged, setDataChanged] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if formData is different from the data
    if (dataChanged) {
      setData(formData);
      // Reset the flag to false
      setDataChanged(false);
    }
  }, [dataChanged, formData, setData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set the flag to true when formData changes
    setDataChanged(true);
  }, [formData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Form comp</h2>
      <form>
        <input name="name" {...register('name')} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```